# Postgres : Executing SELECT within a transaction does not return most recent rows

Tags: postgresql, transaction, functions

Given a table layout that looks like this

```
inv_items
=========
* id bigserial
sku character varying(22)
name character varying(32)
...

inv_items_stock
===============
item_id bigint (inv_items)
qty int
...

inv_items_group
===============
group_id bigint (inv_items)
item_id bigint (inv_items)
```

where an item may be a "stock item" or a "group item" (with compound items...) I have a trigger that checks before insert / update on each `inv_items_stock` and `inv_items_group` to make sure that some conditions are met; for example, a stock item cannot be a group item.

The problem is that, in my program, I run a batch of inserts inside a transaction; first I insert into `inv_items`, then into one of the other table. Unfortunately, the `SELECT` inside my trigger function  does not find any item that I just inserted within the transaction, thus always fails.

For example, here is the group item check trigger

```
CREATE FUNCTION inv_check_set_group_items() RETURNS trigger AS $INV_GRP_SET$
DECLARE found_item bigint;
BEGIN
   SELECT id INTO found_item FROM inv_groups_vw WHERE id = NEW.group_id;
   IF found_item IS NULL THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid group item';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$INV_GRP_SET$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER inv_check_set_group_items BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON inv_items_group
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE inv_check_set_group_items();
```

Where `inv_groups_vw` is a `VIEW` with the predefined `SELECT` to return all the item groups inside `inv_items`.

Is the problem with the `VIEW` or the `FUNCTION`? What can I do to fix this and be able to select rows of newly inserted items within the transaction? ... am I missing anything else?

Could it be that my condition `IF found_item IS NULL THEN` is flawed?

Comment: I don't understand why you have the trigger in the first place. Looks like you are trying to implement a foreign key check there, so why not just _use_ a foreign key constraint?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can have an FK on a view?

Comment: No, but the ids you are looking for have to be stored in some table, and you can have a FK to that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, no that won't work. The constraint is based on a `WHERE` which is a little more complexe than a simple FK check...

Comment: *Unfortunately, the SELECT inside my trigger function does not find any item that I just inserted within the transaction, thus always fails*. It should find just-inserted rows; that's why PostgreSQL has the command-counter (internal), to ensure that functions can see rows that just got inserted. Rather than using `SELECT INTO`, try using `PERFORM` and just test the `FOUND` special variable. Overall though, it's really hard to diagnose things like this without a self contained test case - can you simplify it down to something you can publish as a .sql file / sqlfiddle?

Comment: @CraigRinger what do you mean by "command-counter" ?

Comment: @YanickRochon Forget I mentioned it. It's an internal implementation detail in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I think your problem is simply having a `BEFORE` trigger - it fires _before_ the row is inserted which cannot appear in the view yet.  Change it to `AFTER` and (after considering @CraigRinger's suggestion) you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is simply having a `BEFORE` trigger - it fires *before* the row is inserted which cannot appear in the view yet. Change it to `AFTER` and (after considering Craig's suggestion) you are done.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Meanwhile, I disabled the trigger while I test the interfaces. There's already validation inside the application and the trigger is simply as a second layer validation...